# How to align 2 images side by side with 1 floating to the left and the other to the right?

Tags: html, css

This is the problem I am having: I am able to align 2 images side by side, but I would like it, if 1 of them is floating to the left and the other to the right.

If someone can make an example of it, I will appreciate it very much.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="image123">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img src="../images/over_mijzelf.gif" height="188" width="600" />
        <p>#</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img class="middle-img" src="../images/mijn_hond.gif"/ height="188" width="600" />
        <p>#</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Style:

```
<style>
.imageContainer {
    float: left;
}
.imageContainer {
    float: right;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}
<style/>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: set container to the width you want, set float:left on one and float:right on the other

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code

Comment: I have added the code, sorry for the inaudibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are applying conflicting styles to the exact same CSS class, `imageContainer`. CSS classes define a single set of behaviors that apply to multiple elements, so one class cannot define both `float: left` and `float: right`. One easy way to fix this is to break your class into two, one for each object, so for instance `imageContainerLeft` and `imageContainerRight`.

Here is a **live JSFiddle demo** of how this would work: https://jsfiddle.net/2q18dqju/

Here is how you would change your code:

```
<div class="image123">
    <div class="imageContainerLeft">
        <img src="../images/over_mijzelf.gif" height="188" width="600" />
        <p>#</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainerRight">
        <img class="middle-img" src="../images/mijn_hond.gif"/ height="188" width="600" />
        <p>#</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageContainerLeft {
    float: left;
}
.imageContainerRight {
    float: right;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, actually I had tried myself this already, but I made a typo -_-. But thanks!